# How can I fix "error: unable to open include file `bootMain.asm': No such file or directory"? The file is there, but NASM doesn't seem to find it

Tags: assembly, nasm

So I was making an OS bootloader and I seperated part of it, and when I included the other .asm file, I tried assembling it, and it saaid that the file didn't exist. Any ideas?

`

```
[org 0x7c00]
KERNEL_OFFSET equ 0x1000 ; The same one we used when linking the kernel

    mov [BOOT_DRIVE], dl ; Remember that the BIOS sets us the boot drive in 'dl' on boot
    mov bp, 0x9000
    mov sp, bp

    mov bx, MSG_REAL_MODE 
    call print
    call print_nl

    call load_kernel ; read the kernel from disk
    call switch_to_pm ; disable interrupts, load GDT,  etc. Finally jumps to 'BEGIN_PM'
    jmp $ ; Never executed

%include "bootMain.asm" ; Include the rest of the bootloader
mov cx, 01001111b

; Fill in the extra bytes
times 510 - ($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

`

I tried combining the two files into one, and that ended up making the assembled file more than 512 bytes. I expected it to be 512 bytes, but adding the extra 0s wasn't enough for NASM. Now, mind you, when I removed the line to fill in the rest of the sector with 0s, it made no difference to the size.

Comment: If, while combining the files, you already had more than 512 bytes, why would you still "add the extra 0s"?

Comment: You could include the full path to your BOOTMAIN.ASM file, like in "C:\NASM\PROJECTS\BOOTMAIN.ASM"

Comment: If you can't stay below the 512-bytes limit, then move some stuff to the kernel. Switching to protected mode is typically not what you should do in a boot**load**er. You just need to **load** the second stage as the name already suggests.

Comment: The relative path is probably relative to the directory containing the file, rather than the current directory you were CDed to when your ran `nasm`.